# How to handle questions about reconciling the Bible to history?

Tags: discussion

In one of my [old answers](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5652/4277), I challenged the accuracy of Luke with references.  However once could say that Luke is right and the calculations and other references are either wrong OR there was a divine intervention.  When answering questions which can be answered with extra-biblical empirical information, how do we handle the "fundamentalist" rebukes?  I am not picking on fundamentalist specifically, but they were an easy practical example - sorry if I offended.

Comment: OR you can take a different approach altogether, as Narnian's answer did.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude while I respect Narnian for his intelligence and knowledge on this and other subjects, I find his answer lacking in that it is basically a link only answer with some highlighted information.  I do not believe that you can derive an answer from reading the text that he placed - without following links, etc.  Other obviously disagree with me on this as he has +15.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't followed the links when I upvoted his answer in December. I only did just now when you mentioned them. He summarized the information contained in them in his own words (several paragraphs worth). And it comes down to this: "there is ample evidence to resolve this apparent discrepency when we pull back from the assumption that there was only one census that must be connected between Josephus and Luke." I think he spells out the answer just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Don't answer questions asking how a contradiction can be reconciled by saying it can't be reconciled. There are some Christians who believe that every contradiction can be reconciled. If you're not one of them, then don't answer the questions directed to them. That's not a valid answer for those types of questions.

Comment: If there is no reconsiliation, then that is a valid answer if it is backed with facts explaining why.

Comment: @TheFreemason I don't thing so. That's like answering biblical basis questions with the basis for the opposite belief. There are some Christians who believe that every contradiction can be reconciled. If you're not one of them, then don't answer the questions directed to them.

Comment: @TheFreemason: If there is no answer to the question, the proper answer is not to answer, and let the absence of the answer speak for itself. The absence of an answer *now* does not mean there will always be an answer. Humanity makes new discoveries all the time, and it's a *very common occurrence* that questions on SE *become* answerable months or years after they are initially asked. Even in areas of Biblical research this is possible.

Comment: Antinomy anyone? Actually, there are plenty of irreconcilable contradictions that Christians admit to, but I know what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm slightly put off by this stance as someone could answer a question without information needed to correctly answer.  For example, without my research on the various eclipses, etc as found in my answer, someone could answer the question blindly.  I'm not exactly sure how to make my argument against this being an acceptable method.  Maybe we need more meta questions for a specific question to reveal more of the problem?  (I'm suggesting that my answer should be in meta)

Comment: @Flimzy did you mean "does not mean that there will always be no answer"?

Comment: @WalterMitty: Yes, I did.